# Forming a loop to concatenate multiple .csv files into one .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
list1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/list1.csv')
list2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/list2.csv')
list3 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/list3.csv')

files = [list1, list2, list3]
  for list in files:
list_stacked = pd.concat([list])
```

list_stacked is only list3 why is it not concatenating all lists vertically?

Comment: Can you please share the data in the CSV files?

Comment: you just need `list_stacked = pd.concat(files,axis=1)`...there is no requirement of a for loop and you are looking for `axis=1` parameter

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.concat(list)` concatenates all of the dataframes passed into the list. Since you're going over each file, and setting `list_stacked` to `pd.concat(list)` every time, `list_stacked` is `list3`, because `list3` was the last DF iterated over.

To concatenate all of the dataframes, use `list_stacked = pd.concat(files)`. Since you've gotta use a loop, then go over each DF, and set `list_stacked` to the concatenated version of `list_stacked` and the DF

```py
list1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/list1.csv')
list2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/list2.csv')
list3 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/list3.csv')

files = [list1, list2, list3]
# Create an empty dataframe, 'cause Python would raise a NameError
# saying that it doesn't recognize `list_stacked`.
list_stacked = pd.DataFrame() 
for file in files:
    list_stacked = pd.concat([list_stacked, file])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

Yes, that works but I need to concatenate using a loop, how would this be possible?

Comment: Why do you need to concatenate using a loop? I've edited the answer, anyway